# Angular 7 - rxjs - Unable to get response data when response status code is 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Tags: angular, angular7, rxjs6

Angular 7 - rxjs - Unable to get response data when response code is 422

**Request**

```
Request URL: url
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

**api_service.ts has**

```
validate(){
    return this.http.post<any>(url).pipe(
        map(res => res || []),
        catchError(error => throwError(error.message || error))
    );
}
```

**While calling api service validateCard**

```
this._apiService.validate().subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res)
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

HttpInterceptor

```
return next.handle(request)
.pipe(tap(
    (response: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        return response
    },
    (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.warn('ERROR Interceptor', error);
        return error
    },
    () => {
        console.log("completed successfully");
    }
))
```

Issue is it doesn't even console log anything.
and in catchError(error) error is undefined.

Comment: yes i get error json from backend - 
{"errors":["card details are invalid"]}

Comment: Try this: `validate() {return this.http.get<any>(url)}`

Comment: no doesn't work

Comment: Why does it say `Request Method: POST` but you call `this.http.get`?

Comment: edited it back, it is a post

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an HTTP interceptor that runs unknowingly?

Maybe you can write a test for the service to test the behavior in isolation.
For me this test worked and I could catch the, in my case mocked, error response.

```js
describe('DogService', () => {
    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
    let service: DogService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [DogService],
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
        });

        httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
        service = TestBed.get(DogService);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        httpTestingController.verify();
    });

    it('should throw 422 error with data', () => {
        service.likeDoggo().subscribe(
            data => console.log("SUCCESS"),
            error => {
                expect(error.status).toBe(422);
            }
        );

        const mockedResponse = { status: 422, statusText: 'Bad Request' };
        const data = {
            errors: ['Invalid request parameters']
        };

        httpTestingController.expectOne('http://test.at/doggo').flush(data, mockedResponse);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks :), This helped, there was another interceptor running ```ErrorInterceptor``` which was not allowing the my HTTP interceptor to get any error message.

Answer (score 0):

with the help from @ChrisY's comment, I could find that
there were multiple interceptors running

by changing the error function to `throw return throwError(error);`
I was able to get the correct error response

ErrorInterceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
          tap(
            event => { },
            error => {
              if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                  return throwError(error);
              }
            }
          )
        );
    }
```